# How to re-create the ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin## principal

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting a bunch of errors in my MS SQL Server logs about a missing `##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##` principal. I went to check the master database and yes, it is indeed missing. I don't know how this happened.

How do I recreate this principal?

Answer (score 7):

Any account enclosed in "##" are [certificate based accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) and you will not be able to simply create them as you would other logins/users. If you have a backup of the master database prior to the accounts disappearing you could might try restoring the database to get them back. Other than that I suspect you will need to reinstall or try rebuilding the master database.

Read through these two articles ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-to-rebuild-system-databases-in-sql-server-2008)) for rebuilding the system databases. I would suggest taking a backup of the current state of the system databases. Script out all the logins you have in master as you will loose these.

Comment: I don't have a backup of master unfortunately, how can I rebuild it without reinstalling the entire product? Thank you...

Comment: Mmh, ok so I did what you said, I rebuilt the system databases, following the MS guides you posted. Unfortunately it screwed up the system big time, basically it lost all logins, databases, etc... Fortunately I had a backup of the master db from this morning so I could restore everything. Is there something special I can do to avoid losing everything when I rebuild the system dbs? I looked at the MS guides and nowhere do they mention that all data will be lost...

Comment: A rebuild of master is basically starting over with an empty (or "new") master database for that instance. All logins will have to be recreated and user databases reattached. There is not really any way around that, it is the reason having backups of your system databases is about as important (if not more) than user database backups.

Comment: After rebuilding the master database you need to create the logins.  You'll need to script them out using sp_help_revlogin before you rebuild the master database.  After the master database is rebuilt you need to then attach all the databases back to the instance using sp_attach_db or management studio.  There's no getting around this.  Also start taking daily backups of your system databases (I'm assuming your user databases are already being backed up).

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently re-install sql server and/or recreate server logins?

try

exec sp_change_users_login ‘report’  and if ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin## comes up try sp_change_user_login with autofix.

If it exists in server login, but not in msdb and master databases -

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  User [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##]    
CREATE USER [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##] FOR LOGIN   [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##]  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

GO

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. Nothing comes up after running the report.

Comment: So the ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin## exists in server logins, but you can't find the corresponding users in msdb and master databases? If yes, then create the user (updated answer with create script) -

Comment: That did not work either, it just created a new regular user in master, called ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##. When running the report it still returns nothing.

Comment: Then take @Shawn Melton's answer and rebuild the system databases.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to get the Sid of the deleted logins,

```
use  msdb

go
sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

Take the Sids from above and place them below in place of ,

```
CREATE LOGIN [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##] WITH PASSWORD = 0x0100EBB95886A3A65AD6C770157B4E767D146D83E079A3A33321 HASHED,

SID = <Sid>, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_POLICY = ON, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF; ALTER LOGIN [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##] DISABLE
```

```
CREATE LOGIN [##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##] WITH PASSWORD = 0x01008D22A249DF5EF3B79ED321563A1DCCDC9CFC5FF954DD2D0F HASHED,
    
SID = <Sid>, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_POLICY = ON, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF; ALTER LOGIN [##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##] DISABLE
```

[Source](https://dba-dave.blogspot.com/2014/04/dont-delete-mspolicyeventprocessinglogi.html)

Comment: i tried this and I can see the logins created successfully. however we are only updating the SID, the passwords in the commands above are unchanged, so I'm not sure if it's recreating them perfectly. Any inputs appreciated.